# Export reusable Javascript function in Cypress test spec file

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am trying to have a reusable component in my Cypress spec file, which is organized by our system 'services'. There are code pieces that I would like to make available as component for other JS files.
However, I found the 'import' statement results in running of B.js's test cases, and I cannot find a way to avoid 'Testcase B' from running.
I know there is custom commands in Cypress, but in my case, I would like to use pure JS to organize my component. Thank you.

[image]

**A.js**

```
import {functionInB as helloB } from "./B"

describe(`A`, () => {
    it(`01 Testcase A`, () => {
      let result = helloB()
      console.log(result)
    })
});
```

**B.js**

```
describe(`B`, () => {
  it(`01 Testcase B`, () => {
        //let result = Hello2()
        console.log("inside hello B")
    })
});

export function functionInB(){
  return "Do something in functionInB"
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit this line - However, I found the 'import' statement results in running of B.js's test cases, and I cannot find a way to avoid 'Testcase B' from running.

Comment: I just added a picture to illustrate. When I run A.js in Cypress, I don't expect test case from B.js to be run. I believe Cypress function is some sort of "just run" when it get imported. It seems the 'import {functionInB as helloB } from "./B"'  doesn't just import the function 'helloB', it actually imports the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to stop a script running on import (or `require()` or dynamic `import()`).

In Python `__main__` ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)) is used to determine if a module is called at the "top level".

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    # execute only if run as a script
    main()
```

It's a bit hacky, but you can use `Cypress.spec.name` to do the same thing and only run B's code when it is the current spec.

```js
if (Cypress.spec.name === 'B.js') {

  describe(`B`, () => {
    it(`01 Testcase B`, () => {
        //let result = Hello2()
        console.log("inside hello B")
    })
  });

}

export function functionInB(){
  return "Do something in functionInB"
}
```

---

The "javascript way" would be to move `functionInB()` to a utility file and import in it both tests, but I guess you already know that.